# Code behind not firing after jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

My code behind is not firing after my jQuery...any suggestions?

jQuery

```
 $('[id$=buttontest]').click(function () {
            $('#myForm').submit();
            $("#modal_dialog").dialog('close');

        });
```

ASP

```
<asp:Button Text="Submit" runat="server" id ="buttontest" OnClick="buttontest_OnClick"/>
```

**Edit**

I've change the code to just close the dialog box but the OnClick event is still not firing for the asp:Buttton

I've also included what is rendered at run time for the OnClick event

```
 <input type="submit" name="Detail1$buttontest" value="Submit" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;Detail1$buttontest&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="Detail1_buttontest" />
```

**Edit 2**

I've made some progress on the problem by using:

```
function forceClick() {

       __doPostBack(<%= hiddenBtn.UniqueID %>, '');
```

The issue is, the button is on .ascx page and when I run in browser it is looking for the .aspx that parents the ascx. page. Any way to force it too look on the .ascx page?

**EDIT 3**

I resolved the issue by creating the submit button with jQuery and calling a JavaScript function on click to do postback on a hidden button.

Comment: you are submitting the form, it may rediredct to action page

Comment: i tested that by removing the form and form submission and only using a text area, once the buttontest was closed, i had a function in the codebehind to find the control. it still never hit the code behind.

Comment: i don't think it will help, but the asp:button is wrapped in a div

Comment: From the client's perspective, the ASCX is merged into the ASPX and therefore there is no difference.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using jQuery's [`$.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) event handler.

This is because `$.click` is bound to items within the DOM only up until the time it is executed. `$.on` is delegated to current and future instances of the selector. My guess is that within your code, the `$.click` event is not being bound to the selector.

Using `$.on` -

```
$('#id').on('click', function(){
    //do something
});
```

Comment: Makes sense but when I run $.on, not even the jQuery fires.

`$('[id$=buttontest]').on(click, function () {`

Comment: @carpeltunnel - I would verify that `$('[id$=buttontest]')` is returning the id selector correctly. Try a `console.log('[id$=buttontest]');` to make sure the expected id is returning.